# how to skip part of HTML code

Tags: php, html

I have the following code.

```
 while ($slideNews = mysqli_fetch_array($slideImage )) {
    $cutNews = LimitarCaracteres($slideNews['textNews'], $maxCaracteres = 300);
?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo ROOT;?>/News/<?php print $slideNews["id"].'/'.$slideNews["friendlyURL"];?>">
            <span>
                <?php echo $cutNews; ?>
             </span>
            <h2 class="nomeGame"><?php print $slideNews["game"];?></h2>
            <img src=" <?php echo $slideNews['secondImage']; ?> ">
        </a>
    </li
<?php } ?>
```

I need to do that in this part of the code: 
`<h2 class="nomeGame"><?php print $slideNews["game"];?></h2>`

html does not run, I just need the part of the text

Comment: Sorry it is not clear what you are asking here

Comment: Please add your expected output

Comment: If you don’t want it to run delete it lol

Comment: You can not just delete part of the HTML as it comes from a database. and the same text is used on two pages, but one of them only has a short summary of the text. and in the second the full text. the problem is that in the first part, in the abstract, HTML tags disrupt as '<br>'

Comment: Glen is saying that you can remove the `<h2 class="nomeGame"><?php print $slideNews["game"];?>` line if you don't want it to be rendered.  It would help a lot if you could add what your expected output is.  Without more information, this question is unclear.